# To find the logarithm of $1728$ to the base $2 \sqrt{3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Find the logarithm of: $1728$ to base $2\sqrt{3}$.

Let, $\log_{2\sqrt{3}} 1728 = y$, then

$$\begin{align} (2\sqrt{3})^y &= 1728\\
2^y(\sqrt3)^y &= 1728\\2^y(3^\frac12)^y &= 1728\\2^y(3^\frac y2)
 &= 1728\\2^y × 3^\frac y2 &= 2^6 × 3^3 \end{align}$$

What should I do next to find the logarithm of $1728$?

Comment: I think you're done.  What value of $y$ satisfies $y=6$ and $y/2=3$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might have been easier if you tried manipulating the right hand side instead.

$$(2\sqrt3)^y=1728$$
$$(2\sqrt3)^y=2^6\times3^3$$
$$(2\sqrt3)^y=2^6\times\sqrt3^6=(2\sqrt3)^6$$

Alternatively, you could have changed the base of the logarithm.

$$\log_{2\sqrt3}1728=\frac{\log 1728}{\log 2\sqrt3}=\frac{6\log2+3\log3}{\log2+\frac12\log3}=\frac{6(\log2+\frac12\log3)}{\log2+\frac12\log3}$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: by the very definition of logarithm

$$\log_{2\sqrt 3}1728=y\iff (2\sqrt 3)^y=1728=12^3=2^6\cdot 36\ldots$$

Comment: Well then: post a new question. I won't try to answer a question's that's already been accepted.

Comment: After your final equality, I think instead of $36$ you should have $3^3$ (this even agrees with the $12^3$).

Answer (score 3):

$$12^3 = 1728 = (2\sqrt 3)^y = (\sqrt 12)^y = (12^\frac 1 2)^y = 12^\frac y 2 $$

$$ 3 = \frac y 2 $$

$$ y = 6 $$

Answer (score 1):

Or: $1728 = 12^{3}$ and $12 = (2\sqrt{3})^{2},$ so $1728 = (2\sqrt{3})^{6}.$